# "fatal error: 'vector' file not found" while xcode tflite building

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm developping an ios app with flutter and i've come accross a xcode build error while building tflite module

```
Xcode's output: ↳ === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH
 CONFIGURATION Debug === While building module 'tflite' imported
 from /test_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:8:
 In file included from <module-includes>:1: In file included
 from /app/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/tflite/tflite.framework/Headers
/tflite-umbrella.h:13: /test_app/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/tflite
/tflite.framework/Headers/ios_image_load.h:1:10: fatal error: 'vector'
 file not found #include <vector> ^~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.
 /test_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:8:9:
 fatal error: could not build module 'tflite' 
#import <tflite/TflitePlugin.h> ~~~~~~~^ 2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer from a github issue:

Open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode, click `Runner > Tagets > Runner > Build Settings`, search `Compile Sources As`, change the value to `Objective-C++`

Thanks to shaqian https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite/issues/7#issuecomment-440128884